# Snails eggs accident

Tags: breeding, snails, eggs

I have some garden snails in a big dark container and I place some water for them in a little jar. Recently, one of them was laying eggs inside the water jar, so I took it off there (while it was laying eggs), but it had laid like 30 eggs already. I put it on the soil in the container and took the water off the jar, then dropped the eggs softly on the soil!

So what to do now? Did I ruin the eggs or did I harm the snail? Help me please, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since I love snails, I will try to write an answer. 
 
Did you mean [common land snails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_snail)? 
 
It's said that

> Each brood may consist of up to 100 eggs. 
> Garden snails bury their eggs in shallow topsoil primarily while the weather is warm and damp, usually 5 to 10 cm down ...

It's hard to predict if the eggs are damaged or not. Normally, in about four weeks you should see babysnails coming out of the eggs. So you should try to keep the container warm, e.g. not too cold. And with some luck, you should get some cute babysnails soon